# Delete button is stay out side of UITableViewStyleGrouped cell background

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, button

I am using a UITableView with style is UITableViewStyleGrouped, but when I set the table is editing = YES, the content cell is scaled so the delete button is stay out side of background as below screenshot
[image]

How can I make the delete button is stay inside of white background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting cell's `shouldIndentWhileEditing` property to NO, or return appropriate value from delegate's `tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Note also that delegate's method has higher priority and overrides the value of cell's property